# cannot use $_GET with if to check spec url name

Tags: php

I want to use form with spec url. For example if the

> login.php?url=test.php

I want to do the function / form submit and return to `test.php`.

I used this:

```
$ronet='ronetfile.php';
if(empty($_SESSION['bool']) && ($_GET['url']==$ronet))
{
  //here the form code
}
```

But it always returns true even if url isn't the main url.
I've also tried the `isset` function.

I want to check if the url `ronetfile.php` in url after `login.php?{url}={here}`

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: Your code doing working fine. be more specific with respect to the problem you are facing.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the session variable.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_GET)` show?